# MS Access 2010 - How can I tie an entry text box to a VBA command that opens a MS Word file based on user's entry?

Tags: vba, ms-access, events, ms-word, ms-access-2010

```
Option Compare Database

Function Openword(conPath As String)
Dim appword As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

On Error Resume Next
Error.Clear
Set appword = GetObject(, "word.application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Set appword = New Word.Application
appword.Visible = True
End If
Set doc = appword.Documents.Open(conPath, , True)
appword.Activate

Set doc = Nothing
Set appword = Nothing




End Function

Private Sub Command5_Click()
Dim mydoc As String
mydoc = "J:\3 - Client Services\1-Programs\12229709.docx"
Call Openword(mydoc)
End Sub
```

So far I have made the code that will open a specific file when the button on the form is clicked. However, there are a ton of these files that the user needs to be able to select and open. To keep it simple, I want them to be able to open the Word file by simply typing in the name of the file and clicking a button that will find and open it. The name of the file in the example above is simply 12229709.docx, but there are other files similar to it (e.g. 12172029, 12124057...) all in the same location. I want there to be a text box where the user can enter in the number and the button will check that specific folder for a file name with that number in it (without having to add the ".docx" if possible). How do I go about doing this?

**EDIT** - I forgot to mention that I cannot show the file path or use a file dialog box to allow the user to pick the file because the users that will be choosing the file do not have authorization to access this part of the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
Dim MyValue as Variant
MyValue = Inputbox("Enter File Name")
Dim MyDoc as String
MyDoc = "J:\3 - Client Services\1-Programs\" & MyValue & ".docx"
Call OpenWord(MyDoc)
```

Not sure if that is what you are looking for but I hope it helps.

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for. I did more research myself though and I saw that there are 2 ways to concatenate along the same lines as your suggestion - using "+" and using "&". Which do you think I should use?

Comment: I actually didn't know you could use + to concatenate, therefore I have always used &.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd want to make your user type in a file name when you can just open a file dialog and have them click on the right file. 
Just put a command button on your form and include a line "Application.FollowHyperlink" plus this function name. The computer file associations can take care of the rest.

```
Sub Command()

Application.FollowHyperlink FileName()

End Sub

Public Function FileName() As String

Dim f As Object

' Must have object reference set to a MS Office Object Library for this to work.

Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With f
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        FileName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

FileName = Nz(FileName, "")

End Function
```

Comment: I couldn't allow a file dialog to pop up because the people who need to choose the file are not allowed to access that section of the network. I probably should have specified, I apologize.

Comment: Wow! That is a bite. Sounds like somebody needs to refigure the network design. You better hope everyone can spell!

You can still do the Application.FollowHyperlink part because Windows should know what application to use to open doc & docx files.